In VHDL, assigning a 2D array of std_logic using initialization array of integers... (slv_2dim, sls_2dim, slu_2dim)
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity design1 is
end entity;

architecture beh of design1 is

    type slu_2dim is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) 
                              of std_logic;

    CONSTANT myconst : slu_2dim(0 TO 13, 9 DOWNTO 0) := (
        1      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 10)),
        2      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2, 10)),
        3      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3, 10)),
        4      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4, 10)),
        OTHERS => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 10))
    );
begin

end architecture;

Vivado is giving me an error that std_logic_vector doesn't match slu_2dim type.  I'm trying to do this without setting individual bits in the initialization string...
However, seems like it should work since std_logic_vector is defined as:

TYPE std_logic_vector IS ARRAY (NATURAL RANGE <>) OF std_logic;

TYPE std_ulogic IS ('U',  -- Uninitialized
                    'X',  -- Forcing Unknown
                    '0',  -- Forcing 0
                    '1',  -- Forcing 1
                    'Z',  -- High Impedance
                    'W',  -- Weak Unknown
                    'L',  -- Weak 0
                    'H',  -- Weak 1
                    '-'); -- Don't care


I know this one will work:
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity design1 is
end entity;

architecture beh of design1 is

    type slu_2dim is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;

CONSTANT myconst : slu_2dim(0 TO 13, 3 DOWNTO 0) := (
    1      => ('0', '0', '0', '1'),
    2      => ('0', '0', '1', '0'),
    3      => ('0', '0', '1', '1'),
    4      => ('0', '1', '0', '0'),
    OTHERS => ('0', '0', '0', '0')
);
begin

end architecture;

However, It's kind of annoying to set a vector with bits instead of converting an integer value to a vector.  Looking for a nicer way to set the indexs of the array.
Also using the more obvious and common type of:
type slu_2dim is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;

Isn't an option since i don't have control of the source code and need to keep the original type.

Do you have VHDL-2008 turned on.   There were some minor differences in aggregates - however, I do not think that will get it done.   See my proposed solution below.

Your type is a two dimensional array of bits:
type slu_2dim is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;

The initialization is an array of std_logic_vector.  That is not going to work.
Lets create a unique type for the array of std_logic_vector:
type slvv is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;

Lets write a function that converts between the two:
function slvv_to_2dim (a : slvv) return slu_2dim is
  constant OUTER_ARRAY_LEN : integer := a'length ; 
  constant INNER_ARRAY_LEN : integer := a(a'left)'length ; 
  alias aA : slvv(0 to OUTER_ARRAY_LEN - 1)(INNER_ARRAY_LEN - 1 downto 0) is a ; 
  variable result : slu_2dim(0 to OUTER_ARRAY_LEN - 1, INNER_ARRAY_LEN - 1 downto 0) ;
begin
  for i in 0 to OUTER_ARRAY_LEN - 1 loop 
    for j in INNER_ARRAY_LEN -1 downto 0 loop 
      result(i, j) := aA(i)(j) ; 
    end loop ;
  end loop ; 
  return result ; 
end function slvv_to_2dim ;

Now use the conversion in the constant:
CONSTANT myconst : slu_2dim(0 TO 13, 9 DOWNTO 0) := 
   slvv_to_2dim  (
    1      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 10)),
    2      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2, 10)),
    3      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3, 10)),
    4      => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4, 10)),
    0 | 5 to 13 => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 10))
);

There are likely to be some syntax errors as I did not test this, but it should get you close.

You could us a function to initialize myconst (I have loaded indices 5,7,8,13 to make it easier to read). Then the initialization looks like:
constant myconst : slu_2dim(dim1, dim2) := load((5,7,8,13), (1,2,3,4));

This is the complete code:
entity load_2_dim_array is
end entity load_2_dim_array;
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
architecture struct of load_2_dim_array is
    type t_natural_array is array (natural range <>) of natural;
    type slu_2dim        is array (natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
    subtype dim1 is natural range 0 to 13;
    subtype dim2 is natural range 9 downto 0;
    function load (indices: t_natural_array; values: t_natural_array) return slu_2dim is
        variable myconst_v : slu_2dim(dim1, dim2);
        variable value     : std_logic_vector(dim2);
    begin
        for i1 in dim1 loop
            for i2 in dim2 loop
                myconst_v(i1,i2) := '0';
            end loop;
        end loop;
        for i1 in values'range loop
            value := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(values(i1), dim2'high-dim2'low+1));
            for i2 in dim2 loop
                myconst_v(indices(i1), i2) := value(i2);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return myconst_v;
    end function;
    constant myconst : slu_2dim(dim1, dim2) := load((5,7,8,13), (1,2,3,4));
begin
    process
        variable tmp : std_logic_vector(dim2);
    begin
        for i1 in dim1 loop
            for i2 in dim2 loop
                tmp(i2) := myconst(i1, i2);
            end loop;
            report integer'image(i1) & ": " & to_hstring(tmp);
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;


If you have VHDL-2008 enabled, you could assign the first-dimension elements individually with a slices of type slu_2dim that are one element wide:
    CONSTANT myconst : slu_2dim(0 TO 13, 9 DOWNTO 0) := (
      1 to 1      => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 10))),
      2 to 2      => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2, 10))),
      3 to 3      => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3, 10))),
      4 to 4      => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4, 10))),
      -- others:
      0 to 0      => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 10))),
      5 to 13     => slv_to_arr_slice(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(0, 10)), 9)
    );

Obviously, a conversion function slv_to_arr_slice is needed to convert an std_logic_vector into a 1 x 10 slu2_dim array:
    function slv_to_arr_slice(slv_in : std_logic_vector; W : positive := 1) return slu_2dim is
      variable vout : slu_2dim(0 to W-1, slv_in'range);
    begin
      for i in 0 to W-1 loop
        for j in slv_in'range loop
          vout(i, j) := slv_in(j);
        end loop; -- j
      end loop; -- i
      return vout;
    end function slv_to_arr_slice;


9.3.3.3 Array aggregates "An aggregate of an n-dimensional array type, where n is greater than 1, is written as a one-dimensional aggregate in which the index subtype of the aggregate is given by the first index position of the array type,
and the expression specified for each element association is an (n–1)-dimensional array or array aggregate, which is called a subaggregate. A string or bit string literal is allowed as a subaggregate in the place of any aggregate of a one-dimensional array of a character type." ghdl produces "error: sub-aggregate expected" errors for your code.

There are semantic issues with your description. Slices are not available for multi-dimensional arraays. (It's why the OP's "...it's not an option" of an array of arrays is so attractive.
